# How to save an API token?

Tags: php, local-storage, token, session-storage

I have to call a client's API that returns me a token that last for a couple of hours. Usually I'll just store this token on a sessionstorage on the browser, but now I need to make calls to this API executing only a script in php, so I won't have a place to store this token and I need to make a new request everytime. I was thinking in saving this token in a database and when its expires I'll just make a new request and update this token. I don't know if there is any other solution.

Comment: database/file/memory.

Comment: Elaborate on your problem. Include some code files and what you have done so far.